# Rails 3: No route matches error

Tags: ruby, rails

I am trying to create a simple form in Rails 3. But facing this issue:

```
Showing /home/praveen/rails_projects/mebay/app/views/ads/new.html.erb where line #2 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"create", :new=>"new", :controller=>"ads"}

 <h1> New Ad</h1>
 <% form_for @ad, url:{action: "create"} do |f| %>
 <p>
 <b>Name</b>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
```

I am a beginner in Rails but as per my understanding , there is some problems in the config/route.rb ..

I have declared following routes in this file...

```
get 'ads/:new'=>'ads#new'
get 'ads/:create'=>'ads#create'
get 'ads/'=>'ads#index'
get 'ads/:id'=>'ads#show'
```

Last is the controller file where i have declared my functions:

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @ad=Ad.new
end
```

Let me know if some more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Praveenks if you're a beginner in rails, I would recommend you to use the scaffold generator.

> rails generate scaffold ads attribute1:type attribute2:type...

In this way rails generates for you the controller, views and routes for your Ads model.

By the way, to create the routes you want to, try the follow in your routes.rb file:

> resources :ads, only: [:new, :create, :index, :show]

I hope it helps :)